# Mapping JSON object with lodash

Tags: jquery, django, lodash

I'm trying to map a JSON object using lodash.  I'm calling the json object as follows:

```
var json = (function() {
var json = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "{% url 'api_temp_income_statement' asset_details.id %}",
    'datatype': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data;
    }
});
return json;
```

})

Which returns a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[{"model": "tempincomestatement",
  "pk": 3,
  "fields": {"income_period": "2016-01-31", "lease_income_collected": "994174.0000", "storage_income_collected": "236216.0000", "tax_income_collected": "131020.0000", "other_income_collected": "0.0000"}
},... ]
```

I'm trying to create a map that has an Income Period : remaining fields relationship, so

```
 "2016-01-31" : {"lease_income_collected" : "994174", ... }
```

Reading the docs, it doesn't really address how to go about this...How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to get. Are you trying to get a list of income period and remaining fields relationship or a hash of that?

Comment: My goal is to have an income statement, where the user selects "March 2016" for example, and it displays the data for March in one column, and also sums all the values Year-to-Date through March to display in an adjacent column.  If a list does that better than a hash, than so be it.  But I just need a "Date" : Income for that Period relationship - I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what the ideal type of object is.

Comment: Is expected result an object or an array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - the result of what?

Comment: @jeffm _"I'm trying to create a map that has an Income Period : remaining fields relationship, so `"2016-01-31" : {"lease_income_collected" : "994174", ... }`"_ Is the expected result of processing the original array the object itself? Or, the object as element of an array?

Comment: For my use case, I believe it would be the object itself.  Maybe not though - this is how I understand I need to accomplish displaying the data... I have a .change() event attached to the dropdown, user selects a month from the dropdown.  I get the month selected via selectorElement.val(), translate the month to dictionary lookup (the object I'm trying to create), then call a redraw method passing in the new data to display the data for the user's desired period.

Answer (score 1):

use `_.keyBy` to transform array to object by key

```
_.chain(data)
    .map('fields')
    .keyBy('income_period')
    .mapValues(function(val) {
        return _.omit(val, 'income_period');
    })
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`, computed property name, `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
var data = [{
  "model": "tempincomestatement",
  "pk": 3,
  "fields": {
    "income_period": "2016-01-31",
    "lease_income_collected": "994174.0000",
    "storage_income_collected": "236216.0000",
    "tax_income_collected": "131020.0000",
    "other_income_collected": "0.0000"
  }
}];

var [, ...fields] = Object.keys(data[0].fields);
var res = {
  [data[0].fields.income_period]: fields.reduce((obj, prop) => 
  (obj[prop] = data[0].fields[prop], obj), {})
};

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#map):

```js
var json = [{"model": "tempincomestatement",
          "pk": 3,
          "fields": {"income_period": "2016-01-31", "lease_income_collected": "994174.0000", "storage_income_collected": "236216.0000", "tax_income_collected": "131020.0000", "other_income_collected": "0.0000"}
         }, {"model": "1",
             "pk": 3,
             "fields": {"income_period": "2016-01-31", "lease_income_collected": "994174.0000", "storage_income_collected": "236216.0000", "tax_income_collected": "131020.0000", "other_income_collected": "0.0000"}
            }, {"model": "1",
             "pk": 3,
             "fields": {"lease_income_collected": "994174.0000", "storage_income_collected": "236216.0000", "tax_income_collected": "131020.0000", "other_income_collected": "0.0000"}
            } ];
var result = _.map(json, function(obj) {
  if (obj.fields.income_period !== undefined) {
    var result = {};
    var eleName = obj.fields.income_period;
    delete obj.fields.income_period;
    result[eleName] = obj.fields;
    return result;
  }
});
result = _.filter(result, Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if my issue is how the JSON object is being called.  In the console I can type json() or tempArr = json(); and it returns the JSON exactly how it appears above (in the var x), but I'm getting the following error on the var eleName line: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'income_period' of undefined"

Comment: I don't understand how the "x" var above is any different from the "json" var

Comment: @jeffm Snippet updated in order to consider the missing income_periods... Let me know.